# How to interpret BRICS fragments

Tags: molecular-structure, cheminformatics

I have a molecule with a SMILES string as given below.

```
smi='c1ccccc1OCCOC(=O)CC'
```

I want to obtain BRICS based fragments which I did as follows.

```
frag=BRICS.BRICSDecompose(Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1ccccc1OCCOC(=O)CC'))
```

I obtain the following fragments.

```
{'[1*]C(=O)CC', '[16*]c1ccccc1', '[3*]O[3*]', '[4*]CC[4*]'}
```

How to interpret [1*], [16*], [3*] ,[4*] ? What does these number with brackets and stars means with each fragment?

Answer (score 5):

Cutting a molecule (expressed with [SMILES](https://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smiles.html) strings) into fragments yields sub-structures.  Typically these fragments can't be considered as molecules for their open, non-bonding valencies.  Derived from SMILES, it is then the [SMARTS](https://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smarts.html) notation which is used to represent them, or to search with this notation of sub-structures in databases, e.g. in [bioinformatics](https://www.zbh.uni-hamburg.de/forschung/amd/datasets/smarts-dataset.html).

[Open Babel](https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel) supports the display of SMARTS-encoded fragments with branching points marked by an asterisk. The phenyl group, `[16*]c1ccccc1` thus is shown as:

[image]

Consequently, bidental fragments are represented with two asterisks, e.g., `[4*]CC[4*]`:

[image]

Comment: What does these numbers mean with the asterisk?

Comment: In the string of `[16*]c1ccccc1`, according to the Daylight documentation, the `*` is a placeholder / wild card for _any_ atom. As for the integer, I do not know the answer.  The conversion of the SMARTS string into a .png, the program openbabel does no yield a visual difference in the output for using either `[16*]c1ccccc1`, or `[5*]c1ccccc1`, or even `[*]c1ccccc1` (no integer at all); a weak evidence that it has have little _for this type_ of processing the input. Perhaps Geoff Hutchison (https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/5017/geoff-hutchison) may help here.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the [original paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18792903/) for the interpretations.
Briefly, the numbers correspond to the chemical environment of the BRICS fragments. e.g. the number **16** in `[16*]c1ccccc1` indicates that the fragment is an all-carbon aromatic ring system. Below is the illustration of fragment prototypes and their numbers taken from the original paper by Degen et al.

[image: Fragment prototypes used in BRICS]